# Intermediate Value Theorem for $g(x)=f(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous and define $g(x)=f(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ which is the difference of two continuous functions. I'm trying to use the IVT to show that $\exists c \in[0,1]$ s.t. $f(c)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Obviously we are trying to find a $c$ s.t. $g(c)=0$. From the options below I have to choose two sets of inequalities which would allow me to find $c$:

$1$. $g(1)=f(1)-\sqrt{0} \leq 1 - 0 = 1$

$2$. $g(0)=f(0)-\sqrt{1} \geq 0 - 1 = -1$

$3$. $g(1)=f(1)-\sqrt{0} \geq 0 - 0 = 0$

$4$. $g(0)=f(0)-\sqrt{1} \leq 1 - 1 = 0$

I chose $1.$ and $2.$ because that would mean there exists $c$ s.t. $g(c)=0$. However, my answer is wrong and I'm not sure how I'm wrong and how we could have another answer. I'm also not sure if I've simply misinterpreted "two sets of inequality" to mean only two inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) tell us that that $g(1)\leq 1$  and  $g(0)\geq -1$. These conditions do not imply that there exists $c\in [0,1]$ s.t. $g(c)=0$. Take for example the continuous function $g(x)=1/2$: it satisfies $g(1)\leq 1$  and  $g(0)\geq -1$ but it is never zero in $[0,1]$.

Consider 3) $g(1)\geq 0$ and 4) $g(0)\leq 0$. 
Do they imply that there exists $c\in [0,1]$ s.t. $g(c)=0$? If $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=0$ we are done. Otherwise $g(1)>0$ and 4) $g(0)<0$. What may we conclude?

Comment: The reason I didn't go for 3 and 4 was because they tell us that $g(1)$ could be zero and $g(0)$ could also be zero so we could potentially have the case where $g(1)=g(0)=0$ which seems like a trivial solution. But I'm not sure if I've simply misinterpreted 3&4.

Comment: Nvm I just saw your edit. Thanks!

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú They are trivial but useful for the purpose. See my edited answer.